# TypeScript function combines the input and output of another function

Tags: typescript

I would like to type the following function:

```
carryOver = <T extends Record<string, any>>(fun: (obj: T) => Record<string, any>) => (obj: T) => Object.assign({}, obj, fun(obj))
```

Such that I can do e.g.:

```
const makeGreeting = ({name, title}) => ({greeting: `Hello ${title} ${name}`})
const person = {name: "Thomas", title: "Dr."}
const personWithLabel = carryOver(makeGreeting)(person) 
// { name: "Thomas", title: "Dr.", greeting: "Hello Dr. Thomas" }
```

I.e. `carryOver()` accepts a function that takes in an object A, destructures it, and returns a new object B, with properties computed from the destructured properties of A. `carryOver()` then combines the objects together, so we end up with augmented object with properties from both A and B.

How do I type `carryOver()` so that the type of the output has both the props of A and B?

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/Wzagrm) meet your needs?  If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I misssing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's my implementation:

```
const carryOver = <A extends object, B extends object>(a: A, fn: (a: A) => B)
    => Object.assign({}, a, fn(a));

const makeGreeting = (a: { name: string, title: string })
    => ({greeting: `Hello ${a.name} ${a.title}`});
const person = { name: "Thomas", title: "Dr." };
const personWithLabel = carryOver(person, makeGreeting);
```

The return type is correctly inferred from the `carryOver()` function as `{} & A & B`.

Comment: Oh yep, type inference works perfectly for this, thanks that makes things a lot easier!